# Set a dropdown's value in React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

For testing an input it works like this:

```
  it('test input', () => {
    const { getByTestId, getByLabelText } = render(<MyComponent />);

    const myButton = getByTestId('submit-button');
    expect(myButton).toBeInTheDocument();

    fireEvent.change(getByLabelText('first-name'), {
      target: { value: 'ted' }
    });

    // do something
  });
```

the above test is setting the value of `first-name` input to "ted" and moves forward.

I want to do something similar but for a drop-down selector.

This is the component:

```
<SelectInput
  label='my-dropdown'
  onChange={onChange}
  options={myOptions}
/>;
```

`myOptions` is an array of this shape:

```
const myOptions = [
  { id: '0', name: 'zero' },
  { id: '1', name: 'one' },
  { id: '2', name: 'two' }
];
```

it works fine in the application, no errors from this part.

Here comes the testing of it, I did something but it doesn't work:

```
  it('test dropdpwn', () => {
    const { getByTestId, getByLabelText } = render(<MyComponent />);

    const saveButton = getByTestId('submit-button');
    expect(saveButton).toBeInTheDocument();

    fireEvent.change(getByLabelText('my-dropdown'), {
      target: { value: { id: '0', name: 'zero' } }
    });

    // do something
  });
```

the above code doesn't work, it doesn't set the dropdown with that value.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Not sure if it's important, but all those inputs are inside a react-hook-form and at the end it should test that the onSubmit is working (it works only if all inputs are set).

Comment: Can you try: `target: { value: 'zero' }`, since your is `value` is I guess the `name` key

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee tried but unfortunately still doesn't work

Comment: Ah, a `select`? For these I've always had to target a specific option and simulate/fire a click.

Answer (score 0):

So, since the select behavior is being achieved using a button and spans.

You need to first click the button this would bring all the options on the screen and then you need to click one of those options.

And then you can finally test that the selected option is now on the screen.

```
it("test dropdpwn", async () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByLabelText } = renderWithClientInstance(
    <MapSignalModal title={title} open={true} toggle={toggle} />
  );

  userEvent.click(screen.getAllByTestId("selectButton")[0]);
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText("sensor pool 1"));

  expect(
    await screen.findByText(screen.getByText("sensor pool 1"))
  ).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Also, to be really sure you can try the following, this should fail because "sensor pool 1" option is not initially on the screen.

And it should pass when the text is changed to "sensor pool 0" because that's there on the screen initially.

```
it("test dropdpwn", async () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByLabelText } = renderWithClientInstance(
    <MapSignalModal title={title} open={true} toggle={toggle} />
  );

  expect(screen.getByText("sensor pool 1")).toBeInTheDocument();
  // if you replace the above text to "sensor pool 0", it should work
});
```

Comment: `import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'`

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Share your full code in codesandbox then it would be more clear what the problem is. Just put a select element and try to test it first removing everything else.

Comment: @LeoMessi Try providing a minimal reproducible example, by this I mean if your select is being build using some library, well and good keep that but strip out all the other components like other inputs. Because currently its quite long code and you've shared pastebin so I can't even run it.

Comment: Hmm, why did you create a new question you could have updated the existing one itself. Anyways I think I understand where the problem is but for that I would need to run the code. Are you not comfortable in creating a codesandbox, just put the same amount of code as in your new question?

Comment: Actually I'm travelling right now and I can't do a live call at the moment.